# Navigating from UITableView to another ViewController and then going back to the TableViewController causes some elements to disappear

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a strange issue in my notes app.
I have a `ViewController` that is a `UITableView` delegate and datasource (I do not use `UITableViewController`)
The table view is a list of notes. Clicking one will open the editor view controller for the selected note.

When I click a cell, then click the "Back" button to go back to the table view, some elements of the table view UI appear missing.

Here is a before and after screenshot of the table view:

[image: before and after]

I am using Realm mobile database to store the data for the notes.

When I debug I see that data is actually populated in the cells, it just does not appear on the screen.

I tried removing the app and reinstalling it

I tried deleting the storyboard and rebuilding everything from scratch

I check the `cellForRowAt indexPath` and made sure the data is being populated.

**Update - code for  `cellForRowAt indexPath:`:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: NoteListCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! NoteListCell

    let object = results[indexPath.row]
    cell.configureCellWith(note: object)
    return cell
}
```

I even tried adding a background color to the labels that disappear to see if they are still there or is it just the text that's missing (it's not the text, the entire label was gone).

I don't have anything special in my code for handling the tableview data or navigating between view controllers. I have nothing in my `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear` methods for both VCs that causes this (i tired removing everything from those methods but the issue remains)

Anyone has any idea on what else I can check?

Comment: show your `cellForRowAt indexPath` code

Comment: check your didselectrow method. may be you are changing colors on selection or you have provided selection style which is changing the color on selecting cell.

Comment: @Venkat I updated my question with the code, though I doubt it has something to do with the tableview methods, since the issue happens after navigating back to the tableview view controller and those methods are not even being called.

Comment: @KrishnaDattShukla I checked, I have nothing of the sort, all I do in my `didSelectRowAt` method is preform the segue to the next view controller

Comment: are you using autolayout?

Comment: @Venkat yes, I also tried not using it and programmatically place the labels and tableview but it did not solve the issue

Comment: Strange. Not sure why its happening link this. without looking into the detail code. can't suggest anything with the assumption.

Comment: @Gil Did you check it with in Debug View Hierarchy? Are labels are there or it's disappeared?

Comment: @arunjos007 yes I checked, the labels are there and have content (in the debugger)

Comment: @Gil Show your `configureCellWith note:` code

Comment: @arunjos007 all it does is updated the cell's labels with text from the Note object. I also tried removing the method and just place text into the cell title label directly

Comment: Are you running it on a real device or just on the simulator?

Comment: @LorenzoB I tried on both. Both have the same issue

Comment: if you put hardcoded strings for you labels, does it still happen? Are you performing some work out of the main thread?

Comment: You wrote this "Clicking one will open the editor view controller for the selected note." Are you sure that the title of that data aren't updated to empty strings? Secondly, try clearing the notes array or dictionary when you comeback and call reload data ( do this is in viewWillAppear)

Comment: @MoazKhan I tried that, I also tried using a static string array for the data source. I think this is a visual bug, perhaps something I did in the storyboard but like I said, I tried deleting it and redoing everything from scratch and it did not work.

Comment: place a debugger in cellForRowAt function and check if you are getting the data in cells

Comment: @MoazKhan cellForRow is never called when I navigate back to this VC, it just displays the data it had before I clicked the cell only with some missing labels. I also tried reloading the tableview data in viewDidAppear, then cellForRow was called and populated the data as it should but the labels still disappeared

Comment: I also tried replacing the content of `cellForRow` with just this `cell.titleLabel.text = "abc"` but i still see the issue happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I still don't know why this was happening, but I installed Xcode 9 beta and ran the project from there (I was using 8.3.3 before) and the problem disappeared. 
It's possible that reinstalling 8.3.3 would also solve the issue.